# Embedding Facebook Connect In A Facebook Page

Tags: javascript, facebook

Our site allows users to register using [Facebook Connect](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect). We also have a Facebook page. We'd like to include the "Connect with Facebook" button in our page so a user could instantly connect (aka register) and then be forwarded on to their account on our site.

I was hoping to use the [Static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878&ref=appd) page application and the [FBML iFrame tag](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:iframe) to simply embed the button but it looks like the iFrame tag isn't allowed in Facebook pages. Facebook Connect uses JavaScript so I'm wondering if there is some kind of trick I could use like popping up a page in a new window that would automatically display the connect dialog box.

Any ideas on how I would include a Facebook Connect button on our Facebook page would awesome!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method would just be a link back to your site (you could even use the Facebook Connect image as the link) to a custom page that triggers the *FB.connect* javascript that's needed.

[Check here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Authorization_Websites#Logging_In_Using_Custom_Code) for info about FB.connect.requireSession().